# How to calculate ST_Union with GeoAlchemy2?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, postgis, geoalchemy2

I have a many-to-many relationship, with instances of OsmAdminUnit (polygon geometries) grouped into OsmAdminAgg instances.

The model definitions are essentially:

```py
class OsmAdminUnit(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'osm_admin'

    id          = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    geometry    = db.Column(Geometry(
                    geometry_type='GEOMETRY', 
                    srid=3857), nullable=False)
    agg_units   = db.relationship('OsmAdminAgg',
                    secondary=aggregations,
                    backref=db.backref('osm_admin', lazy='dynamic'))

class OsmAdminAgg(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'admin_agg'

    id   = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

Now what I am struggling to do is selecting OsmAdminUnits that belong to a certain OsmAdminAgg AND getting the polgyons merged by applying ST_Union from GeoAlchemy.

Selecting all admin units that belong to admin agg with id=1 works:

```py
units = OsmAdminUnit.query.filter(OsmAdminUnit.agg_units.any(id=1)).all()
```

But I don't get how I can apply ST_Union on that result.
My approach so far was:

```py
union = db.session.query(
        OsmAdminUnit.geometry.ST_Union().ST_AsGeoJSON().label('agg_union')
        ).filter(OsmAdminUnit.agg_units.any(id=1)).subquery()
```

So how do I get the union of these geometries, and get it as GeoJSON?

Btw, I am building this on top of Flask, using SQLAlchemy, Flask-SQLAlchemy, Geoalchemy2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.functions import func

union = db.session.query(func.ST_AsGeoJSON(func.ST_Union(
    OsmAdminUnit.geometry)).label('agg_union')
    ).filter(OsmAdminUnit.agg_units.any(id=1)).subquery()
```

Comment: Sorry for late answer, but using func made the difference. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a basic template for this in the [GeoAlchemy 2 docs](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/orm_tutorial.html#use-other-spatial-functions). Essentially, you need to pass `func` to the query, rather than the model, to select the union itself.

In your case, something like:

```
import sqlalchemy

union = db.session.query(
    sqlalchemy.func.ST_AsGeoJSON(
        sqlalchemy.func.ST_Union(OsmAdminUnit.geometry)
    ).label('agg_union')
).filter(
    OsmAdminUnit.agg_units.any(id=1)
).all()
```

This grabs the union of `geometry` values for OsmAdminUnit records matching the filter, and returns it as stringified GeoJSON.

The accepted answer didn't work for me, I think the import may be different in the version of sqlalchemy I'm using.

Comment: it would be helpful if you could explain your code at least in a minimalist way